# Removing Certain Characters inside a String, Java

Tags: java, android, regex, string

My problem here is that i want a Character remove in some parts of a String but I do not know how to restrict the removing.

Example:

```
A computer is a general purpose device that can be\n
programmed to carry out a finite set of\n 
millions to billions of times more capable.\n
\n
In this era mechanical analog computers were used\n
for military applications.\n
1.1 Limited-function early computers\n
1.2 First general-purpose computers\n
1.3 Stored-program architecture\n
1.4 Semiconductors and\n
```

this here example is the content of my string, what i want to happen is to remove the `\n` of lines 1 and 2 above but not to remove the `\n` in line 5 onwards. **How do i remove the `\n` without removing the other `\n`?**. My Goal here is to make the string a paragraph without `\n` after line. like the example the first 3 lines can be a paragraph and the next lines are in bullet form(example). what i am saying is that I do not want to remove `\n` in bulleted characters.

The real contents of the string is dynamic.

I have tried using `String.replaceAll("\n", " ")` well clearly that would not work it will remove all the `\n` i have thought of using `Regex` to determine what is Alphanumberic but it would remove some letters after `\n`

Comment: If it's dynamic, how do you know to remove from lines 1 and 2 only?  The example you've been given is also ambiguous.  You say remove from lines 1 and 2 but not from 5 onwards.  The second criteria is redundant.  Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: If I restated your question as "how can I remove all new line characters from a string, except where the new line is a blank line or the line begins with a digit" would that be accurate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using this regex: -

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.+)(?<!\\.)\n(?!\\d)", "$1 ");
System.out.println(str);
```

This will replace your `\n` if it is `not preceded` by a `dot - termination of a paragraph`, and it is `not followed` by a `digit`, for when it is followed by a bulleted point. (like, your `\n` in first bullet point is followed by a `1.2`. So, it will not be replaced.).

- `(.+)` at the start, ensures that you are not replacing a `blank line`.

This will work for the string you have shown.

**Explanation: -**

- `(.+)` -> A capture group, capturing anything, occurring at least once.
- `(?<!\\.)` -> This is called `negative-look-behind`. It matches the `string` following it, only if that string is not preceded by a `dot(.)` given in the `negative-look-behind` pattern.
     **For e.g.: -** You don't need to replace `\n` after the line: - `millions to billions of times more capable.\n`.
- `(?!\\d)` -> This is called `negative -look-ahead`. It matches string behind it, only if that string is not followed by a `digit (\\d)` given in the `negative-look-ahead` pattern. 
  **For e.g.: -** In your bulleted points, `computers\n` is followed by `1.2`. where `1` is a digit. So, you don't want to replace that `\n`.
- Now, `$1` and `$2` represent the groups captured in the pattern match. Since you just want to replace `"\n"`. So, we took the remaining pattern match as it is, while replacing `"\n"` with a `space`.

So, `$1` is representation for `1st group` - `(.+)`

Note, `look-ahead` and `look-behind` regexes are `non-capturing` groups.

**For More Details, follow these links: -**

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: This would also remove the blank line between the first two paragraphs.

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks for the answer and time. I am no good with regex it confuses me.

Comment: @ChristianEricParan. I'll explain it in the post. This kind of problem is well suited for Regex.

Comment: @RohitJain.  Nice regex and nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your requirement is to remove the \n of lines 1 and 2 .
What you can do is as below:

- split your string into segments,
- String[] array = yourString.split("\n");
- concat every segments by adding \n tag, except line 1,2
- array[1] + array[2] + array[3] + '\n' + array[4] + '\n' ...// and so
  forth